# How to apply bitwise operations to the actual IEEE 754 representation of JS Numbers?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ieee-754

In JavaScript, whenever you perform a bitwise operation such as `x << 2`, the 64-bit float representation gets converted to a 32-bit unsigned int before the shifting actually occurs. I am insterested in applying the shift to the actual, unaltered IEEE 754 bitwise representation.

How is that possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't without writing your own code to get the bit representation.

Comment: Guess this isn't to be generic part of this language for IEEE 754 numbers consists of different fields packed in 64 bits. By shifting bits it's unclear whether shifting is applied to single field or to the whole "raw" 64 bits without respecting the mantissa, sign or exponent field. In the latter case it's actually about converting JSNumber to 64bit integer to shift the latter afterwards.

Comment: And what would the result of << 2 be if you could get at that representation? Shifting bits blindly while ignoring the significant/exponent individual fields would not be useful in a numeric context. Multiplying by 4 would be, but then you don't need the bits. That leaves only non-numeric contexts, but then why do you have a float?

Comment: Point in case: I am receiving those floats from a C program using `node-ffi`. That C program uses the least significant bit of a float to tag it with a special flag. I want a way to examine that flag in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try converting the JSNumber to bytes/integers first and shifting the result yourself.

Using TypedArray stuff available in recent versions of major browsers:

```
var f = new Float64Array( 1 );    // creating typed array to contain single 64-bit IEEE754
f.set( [ 1.0 ], 0 );              // transferring JSNumber for untyped array to first element of typed one
var d = new DataView( f.buffer ); // creating raw view on content in typed array
var w1 = d.getUint32( 0 );        // accessing bytes 0 to 3 of typed array
var w2 = d.getUint32( 4 );        // accessing bytes 4 to 7 of typed array
```

After that you could shift the 32-bit-words in `w1` and `w2` individually transferring upper 2 bits in lower word to lower 2 bits of upper word yourself.

Endianess might be controlled on using second argument to `d.getUint32()`.

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Just to ensure, comment of Bergi is recognized properly. All my code might be reduced to single line like that:

```
var d = new Uint32Array( new Float64Array( [1.0] ).buffer );
```

`d[0]` and `d[1]` are suitable for accessing contained 32-bit words, then.

Comment: Simpler: `var d = new Uint32Array( new Float64Array( [1.0] ).buffer)` :-)

Comment: Indeed ... I'm not familiar with that "new" stuff, actually I was reading the API for the first time myself. My code was derived from linked docs and tested in a console session, only. Its pretty cool API though ...

Comment: Hey, thanks. That does indeed answer my question. Considering the information provided here, though, I've relaxed a little bit the specifications. Now all I need is to determine wether the least significant bit of a float is set or not. I'd like to know if there is any simpler (faster) way to do it, or if your solution is the best option. If you know the answer, please check my last question!

Comment: Without testing I tend to advise given approach over any other one, according to your intention of testing LSB of mantissa. Typed Arrays are introduced to provide *low-level* access on data streams, low-level usually implies higher performance. Only alternative I see is this: build the number with LSB of mantissa cleared, but matching all other bits of sign, exponent and mantissa ... then compare the two. However, building that small mantissa (it's 2 ^ -52) is anything but as simple as the line given above ... it takes string processing and/or sequences of floating point arithmetics.

Comment: Alright, seems like that solution fit perfectly. I am using an existing DataView though, so I don't have to recreate the arrays every call (like the last example)! Provided greater performance on tests. Thanks.