# Is there any way to determine wether the last bit of a JavaScript number, as per its IEEE 754 encoding, is set?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ieee-754

JavaScript Numbers are encoded using the IEEE 754 specification for floating point numbers. It has bitwise operators, but those convert the number to an `32-bits unsigned int` numerically equivalent representation, modifying the bits in the process. Is there, thus, a fast way to determine wether the last bit, **on the original encoding**, is set or not?

Comment: That seems like a strange thing to do. What's this for? Do you specifically need the last bit, or will you also need access to other bits of the representation?

Comment: How is this not an exact duplicate of your former question [How to apply bitwise operations to the actual IEEE 754 representation of JS Numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24564460/1048572)?

Comment: What do you mean by "original encoding"?

Comment: Not a duplication as I actually explained in that thread, under the answer. That other question is asking for bitwise operations in general. This one is interested in just measuring the least significant bit, which could be achieved by other means, such as math. Notice I can't delete the other question as it already has an answer.

Comment: @Bergi by "original encoding", I mean the way it is stored on memory. That is, I am not interested in measuring the last bit of the number after it is converted to a Uint32. I want the actual last bit.

Comment: I think you actually should have edited that other question then. The answer is basically the same.

Comment: You can never know "how it is stored on memory". JS compilers do lots of optimizing, and when a number would fit in an integer they store it as an integer. Maybe you should edit this question to describe your actual use case. What is this float, and why would you need a single bit of it?

Comment: I am receiving `doubles` from a `C` application using `node-ffi`. I am passing those doubles to a HTML5 client using sockets. That application uses the least significant bit of the double as a certain flag. I want to know wether that tag is set, and set/unset it in my own floats.